# NSNotificationCentre without date?

Tags: nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I want an NSNotification to be triggered when a non date based event occurs. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _non date based event_?

Comment: Like basically trigger a local notification without a date. I want to make a notification without a date

Comment: You can use NSNotification's `+(id)notificationWithName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject` method? Is there a reason why you don't want to use it.

Comment: I would like more info on this. Like a fully fledged tutorial. I want like a UIAlert view to pop up in the background. Any ideas on what I should be searchin for? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an NSNotification and add this notification to the default notification centre. You can do this in that unique line :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName object:object userInfo:dictionary];
```

You then have to say to your project that when a notification is sent with the name *notificationName*, trigger this specific method on my code. And this is done with :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationMethod) name:notificationName object:object];
```

There is a full tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_nsnotificationcenter/).